# Firmware Password Change Instructions don't match Software Menu's

Tags: firmware

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455

Instructions do not match my Mac's Menu (current OS) - there is no Startup Security Utility or Firmware Password Utility.

Comment: "This feature requires a Mac with an Intel processor. For the equivalent level of security on a Mac with Apple silicon, simply turn on FileVault." -> Which Mac model are you using?

Answer (score 1):

What is your Mac model? If it is a M1 Mac model, the Firmware/EFI password no longer exists.
Otherwise, on Intel Mac, you can manage it from the terminal with the **firmwarepasswd** command.